# Arrange 叶子 / 落下来 / 一片片 / 从 / 树上 to form a sentence: is 一片片叶子从树上落下来 the only correct option?

Tags: grammar, word-order

This is 排列成句 ("form a sentence") exercise from a Chinese textbook about measure words:

> [image: 叶子 / 落下来 / 一片片 / 从 / 树上]
> <sub>量词 训练大全, p.26.</sub>

I infer from the Internet (e.g. [here](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/179874884204345804)) that a (the (?)) correct answer is:

> 一片片叶子从树上落下来。

But I wonder if two other possibilities are also acceptable:

> 从树上一片片叶子落下来。
> 从树上落下来一片片叶子。

**Question**: Is 一片片叶子从树上落下来 the only correct option?

Comment: Yes, both alternatives are acceptable, albeit the original was better. My second choice will be the last sentence 从树上落下来一片片叶子。

Comment: I'd put: 叶子从树上一片片落下来。There are many alternatives though.

Comment: 一片片 in 叶子从树上一片片落下来 is an adverb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is 排列成句 ("form a sentence") exercise from a Chinese textbook about **measure words**:

1. 一片片叶子从树上落下来。 = one-after-another (**measure word**) leaf fall from the tree
2. 叶子一片片(**adv**)从树上落下来。= The leaves falling one-by-one (**adv**) from the tree
3. 从树上(落下)一片片叶子(来)。 = one-after-another(measure word) leaf fall from the tree
4. 从树上落下(了)一片片叶子 = one-after-another(measure word) leaf has fallen from the tree

- If you cannot change the character or its order in each phrase, and make 一片片 a measure word (not an adverb) then #1. is the only correct answer.
- 一片片 in #2 叶子一片片(地)从树上落下来 is an adverb, not a measure word
- You have to break up 落下 and 来 in #3
- You have to replace 来 with 了 in #4

Comment: I disagree with #4, as both are acceptable, but in 句子重組, the change of a given word is not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why "一片片叶子从树上落下来" is the correct answer is because the complete sentence is "秋天到了，一片片叶子从树上落下来"

I suspected that there is more to the sentence because "一片片叶子从树上落下来" somehow seems "incomplete" to me.

So, 秋天到了, 从树上一片片叶子落下来, & 秋天到了 从树上落下来一片片叶子 both therefore sounds awkward.